# “Se” por nekondiĉa frazo

Tags: grammar

Mi ludas [ĉi tiun ludon](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aventuro_(tekstaventuro)) kaj ofte estas frazoj kun *se* kiujn mi trovas strangaj. Ekzemple:

> Se vi trinkas la kokakolaon, la gusto ne plaĉas al vi. Sed vi soifas do eltrinkas la tutan boteleton.

> Se vi proksimiĝas la vilaĝon, kelkaj vilaĝanoj iras al vi.

La ludo estas tekstaventuro en kiu oni donas komandojn al la programo kaj ĝi klarigas tion kio rezulte okazas. Do la frazoj estas tio kio ja efektive okazas kaj ne estas ia kondiĉo.

Ĉu tiu vortumo estas normala en esperanto aŭ ĉu ĝi estas laŭvorta traduko de vortumo en alia lingvo?

---

**Edit:** mi aldonas plenan protokolon de ludo ĝis la unua frazo por montri kiel funkcias la ludsistemo. Mi tajpas tion kio komenciĝas per `>`.

> Vi ferias je la insulo Texel. Hieraŭ vi aŭdis en la trinkejo strangan historion. Du infanoj perdiĝis sur la norda strando, kvankam en la ĉirkaŭaĵo estis multaj plenkreskuloj neniu vidis ilin foriri. Ankaŭ certas ke ili ne naĝis, kelkaj diras ke ili simple fosis kavon. Ĝis nun neniu revidis la infanojn kaj ĉiu timas iri al la marbordo.
>
> Kaj kion vi faras nun?
> > mi iras norden
>
> Bone. En ĉiu direkto nun etendiĝas la dunoj, sed vi jam flaras la maron.
>
> Kaj kion vi faras nun?
> > mi iras norden
>
> Bone. Vi estas sur la strando, la ondoj ne estas ege altaj. Vi vidas kokakolaan boteleton.
>
> Kaj kion vi faras nun?
> > mi prenas la boteleton
>
> Vi prenis la kokakolaan boteleton.
>
> Kaj kion vi faras nun?
> > mi trinkas ĝin
>
> Se vi trinkas la kokakolaon, la gusto ne plaĉas al vi. Sed vi soifas do eltrinkas la tutan boteleton.
>
> Kaj kion vi faras nun?
> >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ŝajnas al mi ke tio estas mistraduko, ĉar vi ĵus tajpis vian agon, do la ĝusta vorto estas **kiam** (when).

Probable la gepatra lingvo de la tradukisto uzas la saman vorton por *se* kaj *kiam*. Iam mi legis ke la germana lingvo estas tia, kaj Joop Eggen informis nin en alia respondo ke la nederlanda ankaŭ havas vorton kiu signifas kaj *se* kaj *kiam*.

Answer (score 1):

Se mi bone komprenis, vi ordonas al la rolulo en la ludo trinki la kokakolaon kaj poste aperas tiu mesaĝo, kiu kaj mencias vian ordonon kaj la tujan rezulton, ĉu?

Mi priskribus tion en la pasinteco, ĉu rekte per pasinteca formo ĉu per participa formo:

> Vi trinkis la kokakolaon kaj la gusto ne plaĉis al vi. Sed vi soifis kaj do eltrinkis la tutan boteleton.

aŭ (kun participo kaj nuna tempo, estas simila priskribo sed pli proksima):

> Ektrinkinte la kokakolaon vi rimarkas ke la gusto ne plaĉas al vi. Sed vi soifas kaj do eltrinkas la tutan boteleton.

Ankaŭ forigo de `se` bonus (sed mi preferas denove mencii la ordonon kiel pasinton kaj la rezulton kiel nunon):

> Vi trinkas la kokakolaon, la gusto ne plaĉas al vi. Sed vi soifas do eltrinkas la tutan boteleton.

Comment: Mi konsentas pri viaj proponoj, kaj ankaŭ mi verŝajne vortumus ĝin tiel. Do pro scivolemo mi ankoraŭ ŝatus eltrovi _kial_ la aŭtoro elektis uzi “se” por tio.

Comment: Pri la kialo, mi ŝatis la eblan klarigon de Joop, pri misa uzo de `kiam`.

Answer (score 1):

Post via enigo de frazo, la respondo de la komputilo ne vere certas pri tio, kio okazas nun.

Do ne eblas tute certe diri:

> Kiam vi trinkas la kokakolaon, la gusto ne plaĉas al vi.

Fuŝus la etoson diri ion similan al:

> Tiuokaze ke vi trinkas/trinkus la kokakolaon, la gusto ne plaĉas al vi.

Do strange, tamen en ĉi tiu formo/reĝimo **se** estas artifika solvo:

- ŝajnigi ke vi scias kio okazas, kaj rakontas plu;
- alie vi estas pardonata pro la "kondiĉe ke"/"se".

**kiam** tamen estas pli natura. Eble oni konsideru ke en la nederlanda lingvo *als* [nl] = *se, kiam*.

Answer (score 0):

La vorteto "se" montras kondiĉon, sed "se" ne aŭtomate necesigas la us-formon. Memoru, ke la us-formo aŭ la imaga modo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato estas nereala aŭ imaga, ne okazonta.

PMEG donas [ekzemplon](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/imaga.html#i-v9g) kun klarigoj pri tiu malsimileco (originala emfazo).

- *Se li **estus** ĉi tie, li certe **mirus** pri la malordo.* Oni scias, ke li ne estas ĉi tie, sed se li estus, li certe mirus.
- *Se li **estas** ĉi tie, li certe **miras** pri la malordo.* Eble li estas ĉi tie. Oni ne scias.

Do en la ludo la imaga modo, "Se vi **trinkus** la kokakolaon…", la ago, trinkado, estas nur imaga, la ludanto ne povas doni la komandon trinki. Tio estus sensenca, ĉar la teksto rolas kiel aludo, kion vi povas fari.

---

**Aldono 2021-07-08**

Ni ricevis pli da kunteksto, la fluon de dialogo, kaj evidentiĝis, ke la ludo respondas per

> Se vi trinkas la kokakolaon, la gusto ne plaĉas al vi.

**post tiam** la ludanto trinkis. Tio klare estas nekondiĉa uzo de "se", kaj tiel erara en Esperanto.

Comment: Mi komprenas ke oni povas uzi “-as” kun “se” kaj tiuokaze oni parolas pri io nekonata. Do en via ekzemplo la parolanto ne scias ĉu “li” estas ĉi tie. Tamen en la ekzemplo de la ludo la programo scias ĉion kaj priskribas kio efektive okazas. Ĝi priskribas ke vi efektive nun trinkas la kolaon, do ne necesas fari hipotezon pri la rezulto de la ago (“vi ne ŝatas ĝin”). Tial mi trovis la vortumon stranga kaj scivolas ĉu tio estas normala en alia lingvo.

Comment: Hm, mi komprenis la tekston kiel alternativoj, ke la sistemo listigas eblojn, inter kiu vi elektas. Tekstaventuro povas prezenti sekvan situacion: "Se vi trinkas…", "Se vi manĝas…" Kion vi elektas? 1) nur trinki 2) nur manĝi 3) ambaŭ 4) nenion